# saving text written in edit text

Tags: android, android-emulator

we are doing android chat application and want to save the values in the edit text(name of the user) to our database.When he updates it,the update should reflect in the database also.Any help in this regard will be really appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: we tried with edit text preference. But not getting it work

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.So people can point to your mistake if any and also can suggest other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, but hopefully this will help:

**Getting text from an EditText:**

Get a handle on your EditText, then call the EditTexts .getText() method when the user presses the send button, or however your app works. So at the start of your activity:

```
EditText message;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //set layout
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    //Get EditText from id
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
}
```

Then in your send button's onclick method:

```
String my_message = message.getText().toString()
```

**Store data in a database:**

Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db The notepad tutorial it mentions is very easy to follow and will show you how to set up a simple database. That example covers adding new records to the database and modifying existing ones, which should be sufficient for you.

If you clarify what exactly you were having difficulty with, I'll be able to make my answer more specific.